# How does this href javascript logic work?

Tags: javascript

I made a mistake and forgot to use the attribute value in some code I was writing:

```
<a href="http://somesite.org/test-link/1" class="summary-title-link"></a>

var link = document.getElementsByClassName("summary-title-link")[0],
    ele = document.createElement("a");
ele.href = link;
```

and I was surprised to see that it still worked regardless.

`<a href="http://somesite.org/test-link/1"></a>`

In extension with this example below, I find it odd that I don't need to target the href attribute before using pathname? it seems to assume somehow that I want the pathname from the href attribute.

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("summary-title-link")[0].pathname;
```

`"/test-link/1"`

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't make any sense. What do you mean *target the href attribute before using pathname*? Where do you do that in the first line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you convert an anchor element to a string, you actually get the `href` value, or more precisely *"the whole URL"*, and not the outerHTML as you would with most other elements, that's why it works

```js
var href = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0]; // DOM element

console.log(href.toString()); // gives you "http://google.com"
```

```html
<a class="test" href="http://google.com">link</a>
```

This special behaviour for anchors is specified in the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)

> **HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.toString()**
>
> Returns a USVString *containing the whole URL*.
>   It is a synonym for `URLUtils.href`, though it can't be used to modify the value.

Comment: How you divined the actual question to produce the correct answer amazes me!

Comment: I apologise for any confusion, you are welcome to edit the question if you can explain it better. 

This is pretty neat! Thanks